# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am getting the following error message while I am connecting to a kinesis stream.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(Lorg/apache/spark/storage/BlockId;)Lscala/Option;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.getBlockFromBlockManager$1(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:104)
```

My spark streaming code is,

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingTest")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
dstream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
    ssc, "PythonStreamingTest", "questions", "https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "us-west-2", InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON, 1)
dstream.foreachRDD(stream_rdd)

def stream_rdd(rdd):
    if not rdd.isEmpty():
        return rdd.foreach(classify)

def classify(ele):
    if ele!="":
        print ele
```

Initially, the stream comes blank as it takes a while to connect to the Kinesis stream. But then all of a sudden, it breaks down the code. 
The rest of the trace is,

```
17/04/02 17:52:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(Lorg/apache/spark/storage/BlockId;)Lscala/Option;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.getBlockFromBlockManager$1(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.compute(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

I submit my job using the following command,

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar --driver-memory 5g Question_Type_Classification_testing_purpose/classifier_streaming.py
```

I am running the code on a local machine. So if I am giving 5g of memory, the executor should work fine.
The same code works for Spark 1.6. Recently I changed to Spark 2.1 and I am not able to run this code. I updated my kinesis jar and Py4j as well.

I tested my code by writing a Kinesis consumer, and it gets the stream perfectly fine.

Can anyone please let me know what can be the possible issue? Is the empty stream creating an issue? If yes, why am I getting an empty stream while using Spark streaming? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Spark 2 might have removed the method that worked in 1.6... Check the API documentation

Comment: which method you are talking about? I am using just one method here which is "createStream()" and that is present in the library.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError`... `org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get`... How do you know that method exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` is Spark’s own internal library and is using Spark internal APIs (e.g., BlockManager.get). The method signature of `BlockManager.get` was changed in https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/29cfab3f1524c5690be675d24dda0a9a1806d6ff#diff-2b643ea78c1add0381754b1f47eec132L605 so you will see `NoSuchMethodError` if the Spark version is >= 2.0.1 but `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` version is < 2.0.1.

Generally, because Spark doesn’t promise not breaking internal APIs between releases, you must use `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` with the same version of Spark.

For latest Spark releases, the kinesis asl assembly jar was removed because of the potential license issue [1], hence you may not be able to find the assembly jar. However, you can use `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0` to add `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` and its dependencies into the classpath automatically, rather than building the assembly jar by yourself.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17418

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "you must use these libraries with the same version of Spark". I am using Spark 2.1 and I am using the latest Kinesis asl library/jar that is available on Apache Spark website. The jar is supposed to be compatible with Spark 2.0 and greater. So I am not sure what am I missing. Is the jar that I am using an incorrect jar?

Comment: `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar` is a Spark library, not the Kinesis asl library. I explained in the answer why `The jar is supposed to be compatible with Spark 2.0 and greater.` is not correct.

Comment: Change `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar` to `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.1.0.jar` if you are using Spark 2.1.0. Please always make sure `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` and Spark versions are same, and this is the easiest way to avoid such errors.

Comment: Apparently, there is no spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.1.0.jar on the apache website. I found one on jar 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11/2.1.0/
a 200KB jar, (unlike others which were > 23MB). But it didn't work either, giving all sorts of missing class definition errors. I suppose that the jar is not a legitimate jar. Do you have any link where I can find the "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11-2.1.0.jar"?

Comment: I forgot that Spark 2.1 removed the kinesis asl assembly jar because of the potential license issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17418). You can use `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0` to add `spark-streaming-kinesis-asl` and its dependencies into the classpath automatically.

Comment: Ohh. Will this work for pyspark? As I am using Pyspark, and all the examples that I saw for executing pyspark jobs used "asl_assembly jar". Also, I tried giving the  "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0 "in the spark-submit command and it threw an error of "Unresolved Dependencies". I suppose it looks for the pom file may be while executing for dependencies. I never worked with Maven, so I may be wrong.

Comment: It works for me. This is my test command: `bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0 abc.py`. "abc.py" is a simple python file. What error did you see?

Comment: Hey, this worked. I tried using the spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0 jar and the streaming is working perfectly fine for Spark 2.1. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Life saver ! Thanks for this answer